# How to search and download an image programatically in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to search for an image in a website,for example-'pixabay' and download the first image that comes in the search result.

I can search for an image easily using a keyword like 'nature' or 'sky'. But I can't find out a way to download the first image that comes in the search result.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you'll need to do is get the URL of the image you're trying to download, then you can load it into android below like so:

```
/**
 * Gets the async task for image loading
 *
 * @param url - the url to load the image from
 * @return the executor that will pull the image from the URL
 */
private static AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> getImageLoader(final String url) {
    return new AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                final URL imageLocation = new URL(url);
                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                //uncomment if you want the image to be mutable 
                //options.inMutable = true;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageLocation.openConnection().getInputStream(), null, options);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way

```
  Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
                    request.setTitle("title");
                    request.setDescription(description);
                    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "/newfolder/" +"title" + ".png");
                    refId = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```